# Error and kernel dies with shapely/geos inside Jupyter notebook

Tags: shapely, geos, anaconda, cartopy, jupyter-notebook

I have a Python 2.7 script (code below) that scrapes data from a table on the web and draws a map. It runs fine from the command line using

```
$ python bears.py
```

When I run the identical script from inside a Jupyter notebook, the kernel dies (and apparently restarts) and I get this error:

```
ERROR:shapely.geos:Geometry must be a Point or LineString
ERROR:shapely.geos:Geometry must be a Point or LineString
```

I am on a MacBook Pro using OS X 10.9.5. My Python environment is the free Anaconda distribution.

I am new to cartopy/shapely/geos.

Script:

```py
import re

import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag

# scrape bear sightings data
BEAR_SIGHTINGS_URL = 'http://www.depdata.ct.gov/wildlife/sighting/bearsight.asp'
r = requests.get(BEAR_SIGHTINGS_URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

# extract time period covered by the bear sightings
date = '\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}'
pattern = date + ' to ' + date
result = re.search(pattern, str(soup))

# create dict of all 169 towns in Conn.
towns = {}
with open("towns.d") as t:
    for line in t:
        key = line.strip()
        towns[key] = 0

# extract sightings data and enter in towns dict.
# towns without any sightings are not listed on the state web page
# help from: stackoverflow.com/questions/16982253/
#     beautifulsoup-return-next-sibling-after-using-findalltext
bear_sightings = {}
for t in soup.find_all(width="75%", valign="middle", align="left"):
    twn = t.find('font').string.strip()
    for item in t.next_siblings:
        if isinstance(item, Tag):
            num = item.find('font').string.strip()
            towns[twn] = int(num)

# draw the map and colorbar
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1], frameon=False, projection=ccrs.Mercator())
ax1.set_extent([-74, -71.5, 40.5, 42.25], ccrs.Geodetic())
ax1.outline_patch.set_visible(False)

ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.4, 0.33, 0.45, 0.03])

cmap = plt.cm.RdYlBu_r
bounds = np.linspace(0, 500, 11)
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)

shape_file_name = 'townct_37800_0000_1984_s24_ctdep_1_shp/WGS84/townct_37800_0000_1984_s24_ctdep_1_shp_wgs84.shp'
towns_shp = shpreader.Reader(shape_file_name)
for this_town in towns_shp.records():
    raw_face_color = towns[this_town.attributes['TOWN']]
    ax1.add_geometries(this_town.geometry,
                       ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                       facecolor=cmap(raw_face_color))

cb = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax2,
                               cmap=cmap,
                               norm=norm,
                               ticks=bounds,
                               spacing='uniform',
                               orientation='horizontal')
cb.set_label('Number of bear sightings')
cb.ax.tick_params(labelsize=7)

sup_title_string = 'test2 Black bear sightings in Connecticut\n %s' % result.group()
fig.suptitle(sup_title_string,fontsize=18)

#plt.show()
plt.savefig('bears.png', dpi=fig.dpi)
```

Comment: What is the complete error message ?

Comment: What I show in the question is all I got for an error message.